# Removing the need to reset the device before using it

Tags: simulation, verilog

I'm having trouble implementing a controller block for an 8-bit multiplier. It works normally, but only if I turn the reset wire on, then off, such as in the following stimulus (which works fine):

```
`timescale 1ns / 100ps
module Controller_tb(
    );

reg reset;
reg START;
reg clk;
reg LSB;

wire STOP;
wire ADD_cmd;
wire SHIFT_cmd;
wire LOAD_cmd;

Controller dut (.reset(reset),
    .START(START),
    .clk(clk),
    .LSB(LSB),
    .STOP(STOP),
    .ADD_cmd(ADD_cmd),
    .SHIFT_cmd(SHIFT_cmd),
    .LOAD_cmd(LOAD_cmd)
    );

always 
begin 
    clk <= 0;
    #25;
    clk <= 1;
    #25;
end

initial
begin

    LSB <= 0;
    START <= 0;
    reset <= 1;
    #55;
    reset <= 0;
    #10;

    START <= 1;
    #100;
    START <= 0;
    LSB <= 1;
    #200;
    #20;
    #100;
end

initial 
$monitor ("stop,shift_cmd,load_cmd, add_cmd: " , STOP,SHIFT_cmd,LOAD_cmd,ADD_cmd);


endmodule
```

Here's the simulation result for the working stimulus:

[image]

Now, when I set the reset to zero, without ever bringing it high, here's what happens:

[image]

Clearly, I'm using the *reset* wire to bring my Controller to the `IDLE` state. Here's the code for the controller block:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module Controller(
    input reset,
    input START,
    output STOP,
    input clk,
    input LSB,
    output ADD_cmd,
    output SHIFT_cmd,
    output LOAD_cmd
    );



//Five states:
//IDLE : 000 , INIT: 001, TEST: 011, ADD: 010, SHIFT: 110
localparam [2:0] S_IDLE = 0;
localparam [2:0] S_INIT = 1;
localparam [2:0] S_TEST = 2;
localparam [2:0] S_ADD = 3;
localparam [2:0] S_SHIFT = 4; 

reg [2:0] state,next_state;
reg [3:0] count;
// didn't assign the outputs to wire.. if not work, check this.

assign ADD_cmd = (state == S_ADD);
assign SHIFT_cmd = (state == S_SHIFT);
assign LOAD_cmd = (state == S_INIT);
assign STOP = (state == S_IDLE);

always @(*) begin
    case(state)
        S_INIT: begin
            count = 3'b000;
        end
        S_SHIFT: begin
            count = count + 1;
        end
    endcase
end


always @(*) 
begin 
    next_state = state;
    case (state)
        S_IDLE: next_state = START ? S_INIT : S_IDLE;
        S_INIT: next_state = S_TEST;
        S_TEST: next_state = LSB ? S_ADD : S_SHIFT;
        S_ADD:  next_state = S_SHIFT;
        S_SHIFT: next_state = (count == 8) ? S_IDLE : S_TEST;
    endcase
end

always @(posedge clk)
begin
    //state <= S_IDLE;
    if(reset) state <= S_IDLE;
    else state <= next_state;
end


reg [8*6-1:0] statename;
always @*  begin
    case( state )
            S_IDLE: statename <= "IDLE";
            S_INIT:  statename <= "INIT";
            S_TEST:  statename <= "TEST";
                S_ADD: statename <= "ADD";
                S_SHIFT: statename <= "SHIFT";
                default: statename <= "???";
    endcase
end
endmodule
```

I don't know how to fix this. As you can see from the code above, there is a commented portion which is basically always initializing the state to `IDLE`. But even that doesn't work. Here's the simulation for the code above removing the comment from *'//state <= S_IDLE;'*:

[image]

It's going into a different state than any listed above, and I have no idea why. 
So I'd like to know:

1. Why is it going into an unknown state? Why doesn't my uncommented code work?
2. What can I change for it to work as I intend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that without a reset or initial value, `state` and `next_state` will be `X`.  Your case statement assigning to `statename` will take the **default** branch and decode to `???`.  Since your process that assigns `next_state` does not handle cases where `state` is `X` it will get stuck in this state forever.

Your attempt to fix this will not work:

```
state <= S_IDLE;
if(reset) state <= S_IDLE;
else state <= next_state;
```

When reset is low you are making two assignments to `state`, the first as `S_IDLE` and the second as `next_state`.  This is *not* a race condition.  The Verilog standard states that:

> Nonblocking assignments shall be performed in the order the statements were executed.

Since no re-ordering of the event queue occurs for sequential statements within a process this translates to *last assignment wins*.  Therefore your `state <= S_IDLE;` is effectively optimised away since regardless of the value of reset the assignment will be overridden.

There are two ways you could fix this so that you don't need a reset:

#### 1. Use the `default` clause to make your state machine safe

```
always @(*) 
begin
    next_state = state;
    case (state)
        S_IDLE: next_state = START ? S_INIT : S_IDLE;
        S_INIT: next_state = S_TEST;
        S_TEST: next_state = LSB ? S_ADD : S_SHIFT;
        S_ADD:  next_state = S_SHIFT;
        S_SHIFT: next_state = (count == 8) ? S_IDLE : S_TEST;
        default: next_state = S_IDLE;
    endcase
end
```

This will ensure that your state-machine is 'safe' and drops into S_IDLE if state is a non-encoded value (including `X`).

#### 2. Initialise the variable

```
reg [2:0] state = S_IDLE;
```

For some synthesis targets (e.g. FPGAs) this will initialise the register to a specific value and can be used alongside or instead of a reset (see [Altera Documentation](http://quartushelp.altera.com/13.0/mergedProjects/hdl/vlog/vlog_pro_power_up_state.htm) on power-up values).

A couple of general points:

- Depending on your synthesis tool it may be better to use an enumeration rather than explicitly defining values for your states.  This allows the tool to optimise based on the overall design or use a global configuration for encodings (for example safe, one-hot).
- Using a reset registers holding state is standard practice so you should carefully consider whether you *really* want to avoid using a reset.

Comment: Great answer. I just didn't understand one thing: 
-- Nonblocking assignments shall be performed in the order the statements were executed. --
I thought that the differnece between blocking and nonblocking assignments wasthat the blocking assignments were done in the order they are placed in the program, while non-blocking statements were executed simultaneously. Could you be alittle clearer on this?

Comment: @triplebig Nonblocking assignments work in the following manner: the *RHS* is evaluated and the assignment is placed on an event queue for the *LHS* update to occur at the end of the timestep.  For assignments in the same process the events will get queued in a deterministic order and the last assignment will override previous ones.  For blocking assignment the *LHS* is updated immediately.  One way to think of it is that a variable assigned using blocking assignments can be read later in the process to retrieve the new value but this is not true of nonblocking assignments.

Answer (score 1):

The uncommented code is an example of poor coding practice because you are making 2 nonblocking assignments to `state` in the same timestep.  Synthesis linting tools are likely to warn you of this situation.

Since using a reset is a common, good practice, I don't think you need to fix anything.